# Inverse of gradient of divergence, in two-dimensions?

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields, divergence-operator

Given a two-dimensional vector field $U(x,y) \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R}^2)$, consider the expression
\begin{align}
\operatorname{grad} \operatorname{div} U(x,y) = V(x,y)
\end{align}
for some output vector field $V(x,y) \in C^0(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R}^2)$.

**Question:** Given a vector field $V(x,y)$, is there a straightforward way to find a vector field $U(x,y)$ such that $\operatorname{grad} \operatorname{div} U(x,y) = V(x,y)$?

Note that constant vector fields live in the nullspace of $\operatorname{grad} \operatorname{div}(\cdot)$, so such $U(x,y)$ cannot be unique! I have thought about somehow using the Helmholtz decomposition, but it is unclear to me how to proceed.